# Jquery DataTable unable to add rows using table.rows.add method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

For some very funny reason, I am unable to add multiple rows to a simple table using [dataTables](https://datatables.net/). Here is the thing,

I am adding 4 rows to an html table using datatable, specifically using the `table.rows.add` method ([link](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add())).

Below is the simple html code for it with a sample row already present in it.

```
<table id="items-table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Item Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Sample Object</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And here is the javascript code for it.

````
// create a dataTable
var itemsTable = $("#items-table").DataTable({
  paging: false,
  searching: false
});

// add data as rows. Make sure to call the ```.draw``` method.
itemsTable.rows.add([{
    "id": "1",
    "item": "Aardvark"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "item": "Red Bull"
  }, {
    "id": "3",
    "item": "Jack in the Box"
  }, {
    "id": "4",
    "item": "Chair"
}]).draw();
````

Error says:

> DataTable warning: table id=items-table -Requested unknown parameter
>   '0' for row 1, column 0. For more information see [this error](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4).

Using

- DataTables 1.10.12
- jQuery v3.1.1

**What is going wrong here?**

Comment: I have to re-look at it, I have just edited my previous comment

Comment: No, the number of rows isn't fixed - the number of columns are which is 2. So, each object within the array has two key-value pairs pertaining to each column - right?

Comment: I know I have re-edited the comment. Can You please try to set an other value inside the first row i.p.o. `0`. This is a strange issue.

Comment: Did, but that doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I normally do this with `ajax` and a `php` server-side script. I never had such a issue

Comment: I think he is looking for the column called 'item'  and `id` maybe you would try to change the columns name. Try to reflect your columns names as they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the columns.

```
// create a dataTable
var itemsTable = $("#items-table").DataTable({
                  paging: false,
                  searching: false,
                  columns: [{data: 'id'}, {data: 'item'}]
                  });
```

Answer (score 1):

One workaround is to put all the data in a regular table and then initialize it as a dataTable, instead of adding individual rows.

You may want to add `"fnDrawCallback": function` in your Datatable initialization if you are using underscore.js templates or similar, and use `function` to bind events to rows after the table is redrawn. Another possible way to do this would be to use, `order.dt` or `search.dt` or `page.dt` events provided by Datatables to do this. Possibly like:

```
function bind_feedback_behavior(){
  $('table.program-status')
    .on( 'order.dt',  function () { enable_feedback_behavior(); } )
    .on( 'search.dt', function () { enable_feedback_behavior(); } )
    .on( 'page.dt',   function () { enable_feedback_behavior(); } );
}
```